# Why the computation of a Voronoi 3D diagram creates degenerate faces in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine5, voronoi

I'm currently working on an Unreal Engine project and I'm attempting to implement, from scratch, a custom and simple fracture mechanism without relying on the Chaos physics engine. My approach involves utilizing Voronoi-based mesh fracturing, and I've discovered that Unreal Engine incorporates the [voro++](https://math.lbl.gov/voro++/) library, which I want to use for this purpose.

To get started, I've been experimenting with [Voronoi](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Voronoi/Voronoi/) and [DynamicMesh](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Plugins/DynamicMesh/FDynamicMesh3/). But the Voronoi computation generates Voronoi cells with degenerate faces.

To render the result of the Voronoi computation, I've used a DynamicMesh as follow:

```
void AGeneratedDestructibleActor::ApplyVoronoi()
{
    // Sites
    TArray<FVector> Sites;
    Sites.Add({50.f, 50.f, 25.f});
    
    // Bounding box for Voronoi
    FVector InMin {0.f, 0.f, 0.f};
    FVector InMax {100.f, 100.f, 100.f};

    FBox Bounds {InMin,InMax};
    
    TArray<FVoronoiCellInfo> AllCells{};
    
    // Calculate Voronoi Diagram
    Diagram.Initialize(Sites, Bounds, 0.0, 0.0);
    Diagram.ComputeAllCells(AllCells);

    int CurrentCellIdx{0};
    int NumVerticesPrevCells{0};
    FDynamicMesh3 NewMesh{};

    for (auto CellInfo : AllCells)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Cella-%d"), CurrentCellIdx);

        int CurrentVertexIdx = 0;
        
        for (auto CellVertex : CellInfo.Vertices)
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("\tVertex %d: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)"), CurrentVertexIdx, CellVertex.X, CellVertex.Y, CellVertex.Z);

            // TODO: some vertices can be duplicated
            NewMesh.AppendVertex({CellVertex.X, CellVertex.Y, CellVertex.Z});
            CurrentVertexIdx++;
        }
        
        
        int faceIdx = 0;
        
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("\tNum Face indices %d"), CellInfo.Faces.Num());

        for (int firstVertexIdx = 0; firstVertexIdx <= CellInfo.Faces.Num()-3; firstVertexIdx += 3)
        {
            // vertex indices of the current face
            int vIdx0{CellInfo.Faces[firstVertexIdx]};
            int vIdx1{CellInfo.Faces[firstVertexIdx+1]};
            int vIdx2{CellInfo.Faces[firstVertexIdx+2]};
            // each cell has vertex indices zero-based, but the same vertex in newMesh is shifted by the number of vertices in the previous cells
            int vIdx0_seq{vIdx0 + NumVerticesPrevCells};
            int vIdx1_seq{vIdx1 + NumVerticesPrevCells};
            int vIdx2_seq{vIdx2 + NumVerticesPrevCells};
            
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("\tFace %d/%d: [%d, %d, %d]"), faceIdx, (CellInfo.Faces.Num()/3)-1, vIdx0_seq, vIdx1_seq, vIdx2_seq);

            NewMesh.AppendTriangle(vIdx0_seq, vIdx1_seq, vIdx2_seq);
            faceIdx++;
        }
        CurrentCellIdx++;
        NumVerticesPrevCells += CurrentVertexIdx;
    }

    this->DynamicMeshComponent->GetMesh()->Clear();
    this->DynamicMeshComponent->SetMesh(FDynamicMesh3{NewMesh});
}
```

This code computes the Voronoi diagram and use the faces and vertices of each Voronoi cell to populate the DynamicMesh, so I can see the result in the Unreal editor. With only one site, I expect the result to be a cube. However, I'm encountering an issue where the generated cube has a hole (a missing triangle).

[image: The cube obtained after Voronoi computation is completed]

I've used debugging and logging and found out that the mesh has some degenerate triangles and my suspicion is that these might be the root cause of the problem.

```
Warning      LogTemp                   Cella-0
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 0: (0.00, 0.00, 0.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 1: (100.00, 0.00, 0.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 2: (0.00, 100.00, 0.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 3: (100.00, 100.00, 0.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 4: (0.00, 0.00, 100.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 5: (100.00, 0.00, 100.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 6: (0.00, 100.00, 100.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Vertex 7: (100.00, 100.00, 100.00)
Warning      LogTemp                    Num Face indices 30
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 0/9: [4, 1, 3]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 1/9: [2, 0, 4]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 2/9: [1, 5, 7]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 3/9: [3, 4, 1]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 4/9: [0, 4, 5]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 5/9: [4, 2, 6]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 6/9: [4, 0, 4]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 7/9: [2, 3, 7]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 8/9: [6, 4, 4]
Warning      LogTemp                    Face 9/9: [6, 7, 5]
```

(see Face 6/9 and Face 8/9)
Note that when I add one more site, every Voronoi cell exhibits degenerate 7th and 9th faces.

Why does this happen? Is there something wrong with my code or does the computation fails in some way? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated (also any suggestions on improving the code).